Cannot initialize the Azure Provider
I wanted to do some labs and learn Terraform.
I've installed the Terraform, updated the PATH and installed the extension in Visual Studio Code.
Terraform appears to be correctly configured since "Terraform --version" gives me actual output.
The issue is when I created the Providers.tf, added the provider:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm"      {
  features {}

  client_id       = "Redacted"
  client_secret   = "Redacted"
  tenant_id       = "Redacted"
  subscription_id = "Redacted"
}

Then I hit "Terraform init" - appears to be successful:
PS C:\Users\DamianPC\Documents\ej> terraform init
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

But.. no additional files as provider.exe etc. are created.
So, in the end I am not able to create resources at all.
As a cherry on top - looks like Terraform fmt doesn't do much even when I purposely make the code look awful.
Could you please let me know what do I do wrong?
I've tried using other templates to deploy providers, other authentication methods - exact same thing.
I am trying to run the Terraform init from working folder - Opening the terminal in Integrated Terminal just to be sure that the folder is correct.
I have switched the folder to another one, created new providers.tf however it made no difference.
PS C:\Users\DamianPC\Documents\Terraform> tree Folder PATH listing Volume serial number is A06F-7011 C:. No subfolders exist
Added TF_DATA_DIR to Environment Variables - same behavior.

Are you running terraform fmt in the right folder? Also, try running terraform fmt -recursive to format files in subdirectories.

What happens if you run terraform plan after terraform init? Any error?

@RuiJarimba
The -recursive in my case acts the same as without it - no format change noticed
When I run terraform plan I get "No changes" output - where I have inserted code to create Resource Group.

You must run terraform fmt -recursive inside the terraform working folder. Changes will be applied to .tf files. Which version of Terraform are you using?

Were you able to find out what happened? Did my answer help?

Sadly, it is still not working, I am using the working folder.

Version of my Terraform is v1.9.1

Are you running Terraform on Windows or Linux? Is the TF_DATA_DIR environment variable set, as mentioned in my answer? And can you try to list ALL the files in the working folder using the command line?

Are you showing the full logs of the terraform init command? If file providers.tf is in the right folder you should see the installed providers in the logs (see my answer). Please edit your answer and add the folder structure, and where exactly (i.e. in which folder) are you running the terraform init command.

I cannot edit comments sadly.
The work folder is located in Documents and I am running the Terraform Init from this exact folder.
Here's the Tree after running init.
PS C:\Users\DamianPC\Documents\Terraform> tree Folder PATH listing Volume serial number is A06F-7011 C:. No subfolders exist
Nothing is created - even the message says that Terraform has been successfully initialized

Comments older than 5 minutes cannot be edited. You should edit your question instead and add all the relevant information. What is the content of folder C:\Users\DamianPC\Documents\ej> BEFORE running terraform init?

I have edited the original post to update it.
Inside of the folder there is only providers.tf file that I created, nothing else.

You are mentioning 2 folders in your post. Which one is the working folder? Working folder must obviously contain the .tf files. Also, check if the environment variable I mentioned in my answer is set.

I have changed the folder and created the providers.tf inside - just to test if that makes any difference. I'll switch back to previous folder and edit post for better clarity.
TF_DATA_DIR was not set - I've added it to Environment Variables but it made no difference (I have restarted VSC)

Unless the TF_DATA_DIR environment variable is set, running terraform init will generate the .terraform subdirectory into the current working directory.
Please note that in Linux filenames that start with a dot are hidden and won't be displayed in commands such as ls -l or tree -R.
Testing terraform init
I copied your providers.tf file into a dummy module containing only a single file:
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  client_id       = "Redacted"
  client_secret   = "Redacted"
  tenant_id       = "Redacted"
  subscription_id = "Redacted"
}

Running terraform init command:
Initializing the backend...
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "3.0.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.

One strange thing is that there are no references to the installed providers in the OP's logs - for example:
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "3.0.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Using command tree -a -R to list all files in the module folder recursively:
├── .terraform
│   └── providers
│       └── registry.terraform.io
│           └── hashicorp
│               └── azurerm
│                   └── 3.0.0
│                       └── linux_amd64
│                           └── terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.0.0_x5
├── .terraform.lock.hcl
├── main.tf
└── providers.tf

terraform.lock.hcl file and .terraform folder were created as expected.
